# Why the minlength and maxlength validations are not working?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

i am writing code in angularjs using html . in this minlength and maxlength validations are not working .here my code
html code :

```
<input type="text" id="healthcomplaint" ng-model="userDetails.healthcomplaint" style="color:#4a5665;" class="form-control" name="healthcomplaint" ng-required="true" ng-minlength="3" ng-maxlength="120" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9\s\[\]\.,\_\/\-#']*$/" tabindex="8">
<span class="ng-hide error_txt" ng-show="submitted && info.healthcomplaint.$error.required">Please enter health complaint.</span>     
<span class="ng-hide error_txt" ng-show="info.healthcomplaint.$error.minlength">health complaint should have at least 3 characters.</span>
<span class="ng-hide error_txt" ng-show="info.healthcomplaint.$error.maxlength">health complaint should not exceed 120 characters.</span>
```

Comment: Can you include the HTML for the surrounding form? There's nothing fundamentally wrong with what you have here (the `ng-required="true"` is redundant but it works)

Comment: thnk u , but it not working then pls tell me alternate

Comment: **Can you include the HTML for the surrounding form?** And any errors from the browser console, if any.

Comment: if i remove id in that input tag it will work  but i need that id for getting info in controller page

Comment: Added an answer, please check it....

Comment: no errors display in console

Comment: @shiv What do you mean by `no errors display in console`?

Comment: excution time there is no errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Working Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/G4InIeg8AvnIBozl5Ccn?p=preview)

```
 <form name='myForm' novalidate>

    <input type="text" id="healthcomplaint" ng-model="userDetails.healthcomplaint" style="color:#4a5665;" class="form-control" name="healthcomplaint" ng-required="true" ng-minlength="3" ng-maxlength="120" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9\s\[\]\.,\_\/\-#']*$/" tabindex="8">
    <span class="ng-hide error_txt" ng-show="myForm.healthcomplaint.$dirty && myForm.healthcomplaint.$error.required">Please enter health complaint.</span>     
    <span class="ng-hide error_txt" ng-show="myForm.healthcomplaint.$error.minlength">health complaint should have at least 3 characters.</span>
    <span class="ng-hide error_txt" ng-show="myForm.healthcomplaint.$error.maxlength">health complaint should not exceed 120 characters.</span>

    <input type='submit'>
  </form>
```

**Update**

I have removed `submitted &&` from following `span`. If you want to use `submitted`, replace `submitted &&` with `myForm.submitted &&`

```
<span class="ng-hide error_txt" ng-show="submitted && info.healthcomplaint.$error.required">Please enter health complaint.</span>
```

Comment: if am submit the form pls enter health complaint is validation is working , but next two (min and max ) validations are disaplayed under text box but submit the form it will redirct two next cntrl

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use `novalidate` with `<form>` to disable browser's native validation.
and use this pattern instead of `ng-pattern` `pattern="[0-9]{9}"`